# How to find `Selected Quick Actions` in Search layout List View

Tags: case, page-layout, sobject, search-layout

EDIT:
Adding a listview screen shot:

As you can see I do not have a listview named `List View`
[image]

If I go to quickActions endpoint I can find my quick actions (in my case `New Child Case')

But my question is, how would you find `Selected Quick Actions` associate with Search Layout? please see the attached image.

I have looked this endpoints but could not find the search layout.

```
listviews: /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Case/listviews
layouts: /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Case/describe/layouts
quickActions: /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Case/quickActions
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Get List View Header Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_list_view.htm) from UI-API. This provides you all the buttons and actions (only the selected ones as with your scenario) in the response. And that the *type* attribute on the response determines if the action is a *Standard/Custom Button* or *Action*. What you need here is the *list view id* of the list for which you want to get the details.

To get the list view for a particular object, you can perform a SOQL as below:

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'myobjectname'
```

---

As an example, if I don't have an action in my list view as below:

[image]

---

And that I make a call to the API as `/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/actions/list-view/listviewid`, I get the following result:

[image]

---

Now, if I add the action to the list view:

[image]

---

And calling the same API as above, I get the results as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I could not find the ListView named `List View` in Search Layouts? how do you find that? and I have looked at this endpoints `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Case/listviews` but that does not give the listview that i'm looking for which is `list view`

Comment: in other words, how do you get list view id of the list for which I want to get the details?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you need to use the UI-API here. As for how to get the id id of the list view, I added that detail in the answer. Hope it helps now.

Comment: 1+ well I could not able to get the list view id and if you look at my screen shot i'm in the `search layouts`  and from search layout i have layout name called 'list view' hope this make sense.

Comment: Because the selection on search layout will be applicable to any list view, so you can actually make a request based on any of the list view ids for that object.

Comment: I have added another screen shot to show what I'm getting when I query on listviews

Comment: So try using any of the ids except for Recently Viewed.

Comment: Hey if I go back and removed from selected quick action in the search layout and saved and go back to workbench and I still see the new child case??? But your screen shots shows otherwise hmm any idea ?

Comment: No. My screenshots are based on a custom object though. And that in the first one, it shows that there was no selected action available, and the response accordingly didn't pick it up. Then in the second, when I added it in the selected actions, it was picked up in the response.